# Spring mvc Resource not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to develop a basic login application using Spring MVC.When i try to run the project it gives 404(Resourse not found) on start up.Here is my code:

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
<bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.sumanth.org.HelloController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>*.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>logInSpring</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>HelloPage.jsp</welcome-file>
```

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
package com.sumanth.org;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandview.addObject("WelcomeMessage","hi");

        return modelandview;
    }
}
```

I strongly believe there is some configuration problem.Please Let me know how can i solve this issue. Tried seeing various posts on stackoverflow and other sites but nothing helped me out.

Comment: If you're starting on a new project, use Spring Boot. It avoids most of this configuration entirely.

Comment: As @chrylis stated, there are easier, more modern ways of doing what that tutorial is attempting to demonstrate.  Frankly, the approach demonstrated in the tutorial is an old Spring 2.5 approach.  Check out this tutorial on the Spring site:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: thank you kindly @chrylis and Steve Hall.Will try using Spring Boot in a new Project starting parallely right now but i want to understand this mapping requests and all other configs.Thats why i am trying this way.Please let me know where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet mapping seems to be wrong.Should be spring-dispatcher-servlet rather than spring-dispatcher
Try this :

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: hi Sushma.Tried that.But the issue is not solved..Actually i am trying to follow youtube tutorial.Here is the link: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnB4x-oAd_M&list=PLBgMUB7xGcO31B2gBmy1igpZn6LK78-CJ&index=5)

Answer (score 0):

Once check your folder structure..
all spring jars should be copied in lib folder that is in Web-INF and import from there